# Emacs/LaTeX displays _char as a subscript in the editor

Tags: latex

Emacs seems to be doing some WYSIWYG with `_`, as if it were in math mode (in the picture, `_` is followed by subscript 'o', inside the `include` statement. It shouldn't. I'm using Emacs/Tex out of the box, no special configuration.

GNU Emacs 24.5.1

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
```

[image: the 'o' next to '_' is displayed as a subscript inside Emacs]

Minimal text example for reconstruction:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
  Underscore-o should not be set as subscript in the next line:
  \includepdf[pages={1}]{home/er/Documents/records/law/fr/om-ren/20170117_o}

  But it should be set as subscript in math environments like $A_o$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the effect with `emacs -Q` GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2. One possible solution would be to switch to [**AUCTeX**](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/). Therewith the argument of underscore is only set as subscript if it occurs in math environments. But I agree that AUCTeX is quite heavy. It brings a lot of features which you probably do not want.

Answer (score 1):

The better alternative to `latex-mode` from `tex-mode.el` is `LaTeX-mode` from [AUCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/).
If AUCTeX is not provided by your Linux distribution you find it via `package-list-packages` after [proper setup of `package.el`](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started).

If you want to stick to `latex-mode`from `tex-mode.el` and if you do not excessively use math in your documents you can toggle off `tex-fontify-script` via the customization interface. You get to the customization interface by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `tex-fontify-script` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. AUCTeX displays underscored correctly. I'm posting a new question for setting up the viewer.

Comment: @Erwann If `Xviewer` is the name of the executable then Command should be `Xviewer %o` and Viewer Executable should be `Xviewer`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having this problem again: $\omega_1$ is displayed in the editor with 1 as underscript (WYSIWYG). I'm under AUCTeX 12.2 and I did `M-x LaTeX-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem, with an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text) - just use `\textunderscore` keyword. Works both in LaTeX and .org files. The underscore character is reserved in LaTeX.

In Emacs:

[image]

The resulting .pdf:

[image]